# What is the Issue with the Order Table?

Tags: mysql

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS kp;
CREATE DATABASE kp;

USE kp;

CREATE TABLE pens
(
    pen_id                  INT                       NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pen_type                VARCHAR(30)               NOT NULL,
    pen_pricing             INT                       NOT NULL,
    construction_date       DATE,
    CONSTRAINT pen_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (pen_id)
);


CREATE TABLE customer_information
(
    customer_id              INT          NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customer_first_name      VARCHAR(30),
    customer_last_name       VARCHAR(30),
    customer_address         VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    customer_city            VARCHAR(50),
    customer_state           VARCHAR(30),
    customer_country         VARCHAR(40),
    customer_zipcode         VARCHAR(20),
    customer_telephone       VARCHAR(13),
    CONSTRAINT customer_information_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);


CREATE TABLE discounts
(
    discount_id              INT           NOT NULL, 
    pen_discount             DECIMAL(5,2),
    discount_description     VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT discount_id_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (discount_id)
);


CREATE TABLE orders
(
    order_id                  INT          NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    customers_id              INT          NOT NULL,
    pens_id                   INT          NOT NULL,
    customers_address         VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    initial_prices            INT          NOT NULL,
    pen_discounts             DECIMAL(5,2),
    CONSTRAINT orders_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_customer_id
        FOREIGN KEY (customers_id)
        REFERENCES customer_information (customer_id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_pen_id
        FOREIGN KEY (pens_id)
        REFERENCES pens (pen_id),
    CONSTRAINT orders_customer_address
        FOREIGN KEY (customers_address)
        REFERENCES customer_information (customer_address),
    CONSTRAINT orders_initial_price
        FOREIGN KEY (initial_prices)
        REFERENCES pens (pen_pricing),
    CONSTRAINT orders_pen_discounts
        FOREIGN KEY (pen_discounts)
        REFERENCES discounts (pen_discount)
);


CREATE TABLE shipping
(
    shipping_label          INT          auto_increment,
    order_id                INT          NOT NULL,
    customer_id             INT          NOT NULL,
    customer_address        VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    shipping_cost           INT          NOT NULL        DEFAULT 2.00,
    CONSTRAINT shipping_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (shipping_label),
    CONSTRAINT shipping_order_id
        FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
        REFERENCES orders (order_id),
    CONSTRAINT shipping_customer_id
        FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
        REFERENCES orders (customer_id),
    CONSTRAINT shipping_customer_address
        FOREIGN KEY (customer_address)
        REFERENCES orders (customer_address)
);


INSERT INTO pens VALUES
(DEFAULT, "Fountain", "4.00", "2021-4-6"), 
(DEFAULT, "Ballpoint", "2.00", "2021-4-6"), 
(DEFAULT, "Calligraphy", "6.00", "2021-4-5"),
(DEFAULT, "Gel", "2.00", "2021-4-6"),
(DEFAULT, "Rollerball", "3.00", "2021-4-6"),
(DEFAULT, "Marker", "3.00", "2021-4-6"),
(DEFAULT, "Technical", "5.00", "2021-4-5");


INSERT INTO customer_information VALUES
(DEFAULT, "Joe", "Ryan", "7989 2nd Street", "Chambersburg", "PA", "US", "17201"),
(DEFAULT, "Erin", "Clouser", "8720 South Trout Ave.", "Washington", "PA", "US", "15301"),
(DEFAULT, "Karol", "McCLean", "9050 Littleton St.", "Ozone Park", "NY", "US", "11417"),
(DEFAULT, "Jack", "Ryan", "802 San Juan Rd.", "Pleasanton", "CA", "US", "94566"),
(DEFAULT, "Lenny", "Jones", "8603 Applegate St.", "Moorhead", "MN", "US", "56560"),
(DEFAULT, "Jon", "Holmes", "8540 Lakeshore Street", "Cantonment", "FL", "US", "32533"),
(DEFAULT, "George", "Flavin", "253 Theatre Rd.", "Jacksonville", "NC", "US", "28540"),
(DEFAULT, "Moly", "Beaver", "12 Mammoth Ave.", "Charlottesville", "VA", "US", "22901"),
(DEFAULT, "Harry", "Pope", "7646 Clinton Ave", "Covington", "GA", "US", "30014"),
(DEAFAULT, "Jones", "Terry", "113 St Andrews Lane", "CWNDARE", "", "UK", "CF44 1TE");


INSERT INTO discounts VALUES
("1", "10%", "Out of the Country"),
("1", "15%", "Social Media Post");


INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(DEFAULT, "3", "2", "9050 Littleton St.", "2.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "6", "4", "8540 Lakeshore Street", "2.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "10", "7", "113 St Andrews Lane", "5.00", "10%"),
(DEFAULT, "3", "1", "9050 Littleton St.", "4.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "2", "6", "8720 South Trout Ave.", "3.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "4", "4", "802 San Juan Rd.", "2.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "1", "5", "7989 2nd Street", "3.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "3", "5", "9050 Littleton St.", "3.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "7", "3", "253 Theatre Rd.", "6.00", NULL),
(DEFAULT, "3", "4", "9050 Littleton St.", "2.00", NULL);


INSERT INTO shipping VALUES
(DEFAULT, "1", "3", "3", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "2", "6", "6", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "3", "10", "10", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "4", "3", "3", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "5", "2", "2", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "6", "4", "4", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "7", "1", "1", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "8", "3", "3", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "9", "7", "7", DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, "10", "3", "3", DEFAULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Issue with the Order Table?

Execute your queries one-by one and read the error messages.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8aad085d41ee0992f33e62e8f865b173

First 3 queries are executes successfully. 4th produces an error

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'orders_customer_address' in the referenced table 'customer_information'

I.e. you must create an index for FK expression `customer_information (customer_address)`.

After adding the index we see the same error referred to another index.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9976aae257a849cd5e25e2d7df5955e7

After fixing we see third analogous error... then 4th...

And after an attempt to fix 4th error we see the next error message in the table `orders`:

> Key column 'customer_id' doesn't exist in table

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65ed6ae2acf23227e226bd27d9e8a24f

This may be due to a typo in `shipping` in the row

```
CONSTRAINT shipping_customer_id
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
    REFERENCES orders (customer_id),
```

because `order` does not contain the column with specified name but it contains the column `customers_id`.

Anycase - debug your code by shown way until all problems are fixed.